# WAS hosting of queues

Tags: wcf, was

I read that when hosting a queue endpoint all these names need to match:

- Hosted in IIS at: **http://localhost/MyService.svc**
- service endpoint address: **http://localhost/private/MyService.svc**
- queue: **.\private$\MyService.svc**

So I wonder, how can you host a service with multiple endpoints to different queues? For example a service that is listening to two queues… (using two endpoints).

Answer (score 1):

Found out it was not possible to host multiple queues within the same svc. You need to have 2 svc for 2 queues